# Is there a shorter way to this than mulitiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've been working on a project where it shows me games from the IGDB API using filters. But now I have a problem with multiple if statements.
It works but just looks ugly and isn't great code.

```
if (rating != "" && date != "" && platform != "") {
    return "where " + rating + " & " + date + " & " + platform + ";";
} else if (rating != "" && date == "" && platform == "") {
     return "where " + rating + ";";
} else if (rating != "" && date != "" && platform == "") {
     return "where " + rating + " & " + date + ";";
} else if (date != "" && rating == "" && platform == "") {
     return "where " + date + ";";
}
```

I've tried some different approaches but they didn't work.
How can I make this better?

Comment: If it works but you just want to improve the code, try asking over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is another way, but I don't think it's shorter for 3 variables.

Comment: @D.Pardal thats not a problem. Im adding more variables later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an if block for each attribute separately, then use an array to store the result and join it at the end. Not much smaller, but in my opinion cleaner and much more expandable.

```js
let attributes = [];
if (rating !== ""){
  attributes.push(rating);
}
if (date !== ""){
  attributes.push(date);
}
if (platform !== ""){
  attributes.push(platform);
}
return "where " + attributes.join(" & ") + ";";
```

Comment: You could also add all attributes to the array, and use a filter to filter out the empty elements. `[rating, date, platform].filter(Boolean).join(' & ')`. And use a template literal for the "finishing touch": ``return `where ${[rating, date, platform].filter(Boolean).join(' & ')};`;``

Comment: @Altareos This does indeed look cleaner but using this there will also be a '&' at the end like this ("where date & platform & rating &;"). Then it throws an error. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Samball [There shouldn't be a tailing `&`](https://jsfiddle.net/4ws62nyb/).